# Bootstrap divs overlapping when stacked

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm running Mint Cinnamon 21.2 on an old mac that I couldn't upgrade. Mint has User interface scale options of 100% or 200%, and the screen resolution is 2880 x 1800 (tiny or huge). I was running at 200% and the below code worked perfect, but I couldn't test full screen 1920 x 1080 etc. So I put it to 100%, and adjusted the icon and text sizes, and now if screen is below 768 the images in  are all on top of each other. (edit: the rows seem to overlap under 768, started at

```
<div class="row datsk_1_3">
          <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
```

Previously, due to col-sm, below 768 they were stacking up on top of each other properly.

It is possible other css code is affecting the behavior, but if any suggestions I would appreciate it.  ... I realize 'height' is not pro, but it worked previous. I've removed the mumbojumbo

```
<div class="wapper-main-content">
      <div data-pjax-container="">
              <div class="datsk_area">
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row datsk_1_3">
          <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
                <a><img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src=""></a>
                <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=16">DATSK Test 9</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row datsk_1_3">
          <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
                <a><img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src=""></a>
                <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=8">DATSK Test 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">
                <a><img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src=""></a>
                <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=9">DATSK Test 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row datsk_4_6">
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
                <a><img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src=""></a>
                <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=10">DATSK Test 3</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
             <div class="fit_in_there_ffff">
                <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
             </div>
             <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=11">DATSK Test 4</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" align="center">
                <a><img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src=""></a>
                <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=5">testing 2 3 4 </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

          <section>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row datsk_rest">
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">                      
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                        <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=4">asdf</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">  
                      <div class="fit_in_there_ffff">                    
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                      </div>
                      <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=12">DATSK Test 5</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">                      
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                        <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=7">asdf</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">                      
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                        <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=13">DATSK Test 6</a>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row datsk_rest">
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">  
                      <div class="fit_in_there_ffff">
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                      </div>
                      <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=14">DATSK Test 7</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center"> 
                      <div class="fit_in_there_ffff">                     
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                      </div>
                      <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=15">DATSK Test 8</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" align="center">                      
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="">
                        <a data-target="#datskModal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="true" href="/pages/datsk_modal?hpe_id=6">asdf</a>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
  </div>
```

```
@media (max-width: 3000px){
  .datsk_area {background-color: black;}

  .datsk_1_3 .col-sm-12 {margin: 0; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);}
  .datsk_1_3 .col-sm-6 {margin: 0; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);}
  .datsk_4_6 .col-sm-4 {margin: 0; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);}
  .datsk_rest .col-sm-3 {margin: 0; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);}
  
  .datsk_1_3 .col-sm-12 img {max-height: 550px; width: auto;}
  .datsk_1_3 .col-sm-12 .fit_in_there_ffff img {height: 100px; width: auto;}
  .datsk_1_3 .col-sm-6 img {max-height: 550px;width: auto;}
  .datsk_1_3 .col-sm-6 .fit_in_there_ffff img {height: 100px; width: auto;}
  .datsk_4_6 .col-sm-4 img {max-height: 300px;width: auto;}
  .datsk_rest .col-sm-3 img {max-height: 200px;width: auto;}
  
  .datsk_1_3 {margin: 70px 0px; padding: 0px 30px; height: 550px;}
  .datsk_4_6 {margin: 110px 0px; padding: 0px 30px; height: 300px;}
  .datsk_rest {margin: 70px 0px; padding: 0px 30px; height: 200px;}
}
```

Update: xs avoids the overlap but don't get the stack

Comment: I have a feeling that if I could pass even the first css challenge this question would not be a problem